# Regular Expression: How to put single quotes around XML attribute values?

Tags: regex

i have a string that looks like

```
"<input id=a/>"<input id=b/>"<input id=c/>etc.
```

I need to change it to

```
"<input id='a'/>"<input id='b'/>"<input id='c'/>etc,
```

any ideas how?

Comment: Please put a bit of effort into your questions. Chose a meaningful title, for example.

Comment: Wow! Didn't anyone bother to check the formatting before dumping on this question?

Comment: it's still a bad question. what language should the answer be in? why is he dumping a relatively trivial problem on us without the least bit of effort?

Comment: I agree that it could be a better question, but when I first checked the OP had a rep of 1 (newbie) and there were 6 downvotes + 3 offensives.  I think that if it had been properly formatted it wouldn't have gotten dumped on so bad.  I've seen lots of similar RE questions without lang specified.

Comment: @hop - It's a regular expression, so that aspect is pretty language neutral.

Comment: Don;t be so harsh on a newbie and downvote this question.
It's badly formulated all right but it's still a useful and valid question.  
Instead of acting like pricks and marking it down, edit it to educate the original poster and make the question more useful.

Comment: regexes are for matching, not for changing, so what do you mean, "language neutral"?

Comment: 1) why should newbies get more slack for bad questions? 2) if i _could_ edit the question, i would have.

Comment: @hop - I mean that if I give you a regular expression string, then you can use it pretty much "as is" in any language (e.g. C#, VB.NET, Perl, PHP) that supports regular expressions with only nominal changes if any.

Comment: newbies should get more gentle encouragement for bad questions - but it was triple posted, and I suspect that contributed to the downvoting.

Comment: Rob: http://www.regular-expression.info/refflavors.html shows that regular expressions are not language neutral at all.

Comment: @Jan - Interesting link, looks like at the level of work I'm doing with regular expressions there is a lot of similarity, but once you get deeper they diverge. Good to know.

Answer (score 4):

In C# you could write it as:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(<.*?id\s*=\s*)(\w+)(.*?>)", "$1'$2'$3", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

In VB.Net it would simply be:

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "(<.*?id\s*=\s*)(\w+)(.*?>)", "$1'$2'$3", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

In canonical Perl, you could write it as:

```
$subject =~ s/(<.*?id\s*=\s*)(\w+)(.*?>)/$1'$2'$3/mg;
```

In PHP:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(<.*?id\s*=\s*)(\w+)(.*?>)/m', '$1\'$2\'$3', $subject);
```

In Java:

```
resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?m)(<.*?id\\s*=\\s*)(\\w+)(.*?>)", "$1'$2'$3");
```

In Javascript:

```
result = subject.replace(/(<.*?id\s*=\s*)(\w+)(.*?>)/mg, "$1'$2'$3");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
%s/"<input id=\(.\)\/>/"<input id='\1'\/>/g
```

This would also work:

```
%s/\("<input id=\)\(.\)\/>/\1'\2'\/>/g
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to really answer this with just one small sample.  For the given sample text, you can search for the regex:

```
=(\w)
```

and replace it with:

```
='$1'
```

or:

```
='\1'
```

Depending on whether the programming language you're working with interprets $1 or \1 as a reference to the first capturing group in the replacement text.

This trivial search-and-replace works perfectly on your given sample text.

I fear that it won't work on your actual data.  If that's the case, then that's because your sample text isn't representative of your actual data.  The hardest part in creating regular expressions is to figure out what you want to match, and what you don't want to match.  This is something you have to specify in your question.